# Webpack 4 profile command missing? How can I get access to it with webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I looked at the docs and I see [webpack 4](https://v4.webpack.js.org/api/stats/) has a command called `profile`.

When I do `npx webpack --version`, I see:

```
webpack: 4.46.0
webpack-cli: 4.9.2
webpack-dev-server 4.7.4
```

When I do `npx webpack --help`, I don't see `profile` in the list of commands:

```
Commands:
  build|bundle|b [entries...] [options]  Run webpack (default command, can be omitted).
  configtest|t [config-path]             Validate a webpack configuration.
  help|h [command] [option]              Display help for commands and options.
  info|i [options]                       Outputs information about your system.
  serve|server|s [entries...] [options]  Run the webpack dev server.
  version|v [commands...]                Output the version number of 'webpack', 'webpack-cli' and 'webpack-dev-server' and commands.
  watch|w [entries...] [options]         Run webpack and watch for files changes.
```

and also with  `npx webpack help profile`, I see:

```
[webpack-cli] Can't find and load command 'profile'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options.
```

I'm wondering, how can I access the profile command in webpack 4? Was it added after the versions I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `--profile` is a flag, not a command